# not able to pass map kind of variables to maven goal through command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

am trying to pass Map kind of parameters to my maven plugin through command line. Here is how i tried,

```
$mvn -U -X sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi -Dsayhi.myMap=key1=value1

$mvn -U -X sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi -Dsayhi.myMap={key1=value1}
```

None of these are working and getting following error:

> ```
> Caused by:
> org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException:
> Cannot assign configuration entry 'myMap' with value '${sayhi.myMap}' of type
> java.lang.String to property of type java.util.Map**
> ```

Here is my parameter in Mojo:

```
/**
 * My Map.
 */
@Parameter(property = "sayhi.myMap", required = false)
private Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

followed instructions at ==> https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Collections, but no luck., i think am missing something very small. am working on maven v3.2.1

thanks

Comment: I have tried all other like  Array, List and Set parameters. all are working through command line. struck only with Map.

Comment: Why would you like to give such information via command line? What is the purpose of the plugin?

Comment: we do like to run maven plugin through command line( through Java code), So for that we need to pass configurations parameters.  this is our in house plugin.

Comment: What is the purpose of not using Maven itself and using the life cycle etc. ? What kind of problem would you like to solve?

Comment: HI @khmarbaise,  we have one in house maven plugin which does some scanning of the project code in which it is placed. now we wanted to use it through bamboo. so for this instead of enforcing the users to place this in their project pom, we are running the plugin through command line by passing the project information. hope i have explained you good.

Comment: To be honest it sounds wrong, cause everything you seemed to implement is already in Maven itself ...Furthermore you can use an appropriate corporate pom which solves such things...

Answer (score 2):

We don't have the option to pass the map variables in the command line as per my knowledge, but you can pass map variable in the following way.

Create xml file and create one plugin (, for XML please refer maven doc)

```
<myMap>
      <key1>value1</key1>
      <key2>value2</key2>
</myMap>
```

Your mojo will be:

```
@Parameter(property = "myMap", required = false)
private Map<String,String> myMap;
```

Yor maven command will be:

```
$mvn -s <path_to_xml_file> -U -X sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi
```

Comment: working with XML file wont suits my requirement, As i mentioned in my initial post, all other collections Arrays,Lists,Sets are working and with the page ==>  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Collections , they no where mentioned that  MAP  wont work

Comment: surprised to see no one faced this situation.  raised an issue with maven aswell

Comment: @gangadharmamillapalli _"they no where mentioned that MAP wont work_" is not true. [Guide to Developing Java Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Parameter_Types_With_Multiple_Values) mentions it: "_Maps – This category covers any class which implements `java.util.Map` such as `HashMap` but does not implement `java.util.Properties`._"

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and  [Guide to Developing Java Plugins, Introduction, Parameter Types With Multiple Values, Maps](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Parameter_Types_With_Multiple_Values) explains it:

> **Maps**
>
> This category covers any class which implements `java.util.Map` such as `HashMap` but does not implement `java.util.Properties`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630531/1744774) how I solved it.

The workaround includes the following:

```
    ...

    @Parameter( property = "map", required = true )
    private String[] mapEntries;
    private Map<String, String> map;

    ...

        map = Arrays.stream( mapEntries ).collect( Collectors.toMap( s -> s, s -> s ) ); // with Java >=8
        putMapEntriesToMap(); // with Java <8

    ...

    private void putMapEntriesToMap()
        {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>( mapEntries.length );
        for ( String entry : mapEntries )
            {
            int equalsPosition = entry.indexOf( "=" );
            map.put(
                entry.substring( 0, equalsPosition ),
                entry.substring( equalsPosition + 1 ) );
            }
        } // putMapEntriesToMap()

    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Gerold Broser, unfortunately, maven plugin code in not in our hand.

Comment: @gangadharmamillapalli Your welcome. But why _not in your hand_? In comments to your question you refer to it twice as: "_[this is our | we have one] in house [maven] plugin._".